# MVVMLight - ViewModel referencing other ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm-light

HI,

I'm using MVVMLight and i would like a particular VM to reference to another VM's property. Currently, i using the ViewModelLocator.SomeViewModelStatic to do it. At times, i would also like to use the methods of another viewmodel. And also using the ViewModelLocator.SomeViewModelStatic to use other ViewModels' methods.

Is this the correct way of communicating between ViewModels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case I would start by adding *Inversion of Control container* to the application ([Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/), [Ninject](http://ninject.org/) or even [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) (if you're familiar with it)) and registering within all **ViewModels** (you can do it manually or same IoC containers can look for specific classes in the assemblies) and **Services**. Then I would implement `ViewModelLocator` to work with the IoC in such a way that ViewModels would be created by it (then every dependency would be resolved by Dependency Injection and all you have to worry about is to register everything in IoC)

By using IoC you can also use factory methods, that can create instances for you in ViewModels.

Comment: i guess would want to use this approach... by do you have a sample where the ViewModels communicate with other ViewModels?

Comment: I don't have an example, but simply you can pass one ViewModel to another. Of course if your communication if more complex you can use message (like here: http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx) or event aggregator (like in Caliburn Micro: http://iserialized.com/getting-started-with-caliburn/)

Answer (score 1):

At times I build a tree of VM's. E.g.: I create a PersonHobbies VM by adding both a Person and a Hobbies VM to the PersonHobbies VM. This class will have all the commands that span both other VM's.

I hesitate to link the Hobbies VM to the Person VM (or reverse) because it will become harder to use the Hobbies VM without the Person VM (or reverse).

Similarly I create Views: In this example I could create Views for both Person and Hobbies and use these Views when constructing the PersonHobbies View.